# AuthFailureError on a volley form data response

Tags: java, android

I get the following error:

```
AuthFailureError: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
```

My code:

```
public void createNoticeBoard() {
      RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.PENDING_MEDIA_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject stringResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean success = stringResponse.getBoolean("is_success");
                        String requestCode = stringResponse.getString("status_code");
                        if (success) {
                            if (requestCode.equals("200")) {
                                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Publisher deleted!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Unauthorized!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException je) {
                        je.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e(TAG, "AuthFailureError: " + error);
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error! Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<>();
                    Log.d("Network", parameter.toString());
                    return parameter;
                }

                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("extension", "image/jpeg");
                    params.put("duration", String.valueOf(20));
                    params.put("title", "Postman Highlight");
                    params.put("organization_id", String.valueOf(274));
                    params.put("screen_type", "TAGNOTICEBOARD");
                    params.put("type", "IMAGE");
                    params.put("do", String.valueOf(7));
                    params.put("advertise_bit", String.valueOf(1));
                    params.put("start_datetime", "2021-05-06 10:37:13");
                    params.put("end_datetime", "2021-05-10 10:37:13");
                    params.put("Global_Counter", String.valueOf(0));
                    params.put("Venue_Counter", String.valueOf(0));
                    params.put("adindex", String.valueOf(0));
                    params.put("adtype", "Fulltime");
                    params.put("media_url", "");
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
                    final String request = getParams().toString();
                    Log.e("REQ", request);
                    try {
                        return request.getBytes("utf-8");
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                        VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s", request, "utf-8");
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            };
            queue.add(stringRequest);
        }
```

[image]

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: AuthFailureError: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError